# How can I generically refer to anything BOOST_FOREACH can iterate over in boost 1.40?

Tags: boost, methods, parameters, foreach, iterator

I have a method that takes an argument that all I do with it in the method is to iterate over it with BOOST_FOREACH. So I could actually accept any argument that is able to be used with BOOST_FOREACH. However, I don't know how to specify that as a type in the method parameters list given my circumstances, which are: 1) the method is virtual, so templated functions won't work, and 2) I only have boost 1.40 available to me, which does not appear to include any_range or any_iterator. How can I let my method accept things that BOOST_FOREACH can iterate over, instead of just a single narrowly defined type?

Comment: If your function is non-template, it *must* specify the type of its arguments. If you want it to accept "anything that supports `begin()`/`end()` member functions", you should make it a template. Even if you could utilize Boost.Range or even c++11 range-based `for` loop, you'd have to define a function template if you wanted it to take an arbitrary type. In C++ "genericity" usually means template :).

Comment: Well, class hierarchies _could_ have been used to this... e.g., _if_ std::vector<T> and std::list<T> both inherited from some std::iterable<T> then I could just take an std::iterable<T> parameter (which is more or less how such things are done in Java)... but the STL decided not to go with this option.  :(  Also, it is my understanding that boost::any_range _would_ have accomplished what I want, if I weren't stuck with an older version of boost for my current project that doesn't have any_range or any_iterator...

Comment: @DaveLillethun First, class hierarchies are very intrusive. C++ chose the python way(ie duck typing) of defining ranges instead. This allows for it to work with legacy code(such as c-arrays and c link lists), which can't be modified to inherit from a new class. Secondly, subtype polymorphism is expensive. Inheriting from a base class, and calling virtual functions adds a lot overhead. If you need to accept any range, you have two options, a template function or type erasure(which `any_range` does). If you don't have it in you current version you could upgrade or try to copy it over.

Comment: @Paul Unfortunately, neither of those are options I'm able to exercise at the moment (can't upgrade Boost... I'm working on it, but there are barriers ATM; and the method _must_ be virtual), so currently I'm just creating function overloads as needed for different types... It's not as easily extensible, and it results in replicaiton of the same code, but it seems I don't have any other option since I can't exploit either of the "correct" ways to do it. Thanks for helping me, though. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it...